# How to delete whole graph of records

Tags: orientdb

I have a records with links in document database:

```
MyRecord {
    "@rid:": "#11:2"
    ...
    links: ["#61:1", "#61:2", "#61:3"],
    otherLink: "#62:1"
}
```

How to delete whole graph, knowing only top level `#11:2`?

**upd**

So i want something like:

`delete from ...#11:2...` that removes all records: `#11:2, #61:1, #61:2, #61:3, #62:1`

Comment: Hi @zella, I don't understand very well what do you want to do, would you delete all the records of your class, or every records of every class?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a javascript function with one parameter (rid)

```
var o=orient.getDatabase();
var b=o.query("select *,links, otherLink from " + rid);
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    var links= b[i].field("links");
    for(j=0;j<links.length;j++){
        links[j].delete();
    }
    b[i].field("otherLink").delete();
    b[i].delete();
}
```

and use this query

```
select nameFunction("your rid")
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
delete vertex MyRecord where @rid in (select @rid,out() from #21:3)
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: My records isn't vertex, because I use document database, so i think it's only way in my case - using java api at application level...